# Why do I still need to install prettier to each individual project while it has already been installed as an extension in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am confused with how the extensions in VS Code work. The "Prettier - Code formatter" extension (by Esben Petersen) is already installed as an extension in my VS Code.  My question is why I still need to run `npm install prettier --save-dev` in each individual project? Isn't it true that the extensions are already applied to all files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't?

> Should prettier not be installed locally with your project's dependencies or globally on the machine, the version of prettier that is bundled with the extension will be used.

https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettier-resolution

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want Prettier to be your code formatter in VS Code for all of your projects.

In VS Code navigate to:

> File > Preferences > Settings

Search for "Default formatter"

And then select "esbenp.prettier-vscode"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't install Prettier in your project as a dev dependency, the version of Prettier on your VSCode will be applied. This may introduce a problem later on in your project. Let's say you built a project in the year 2020 and your project has been maintained till 2021 and ongoing. If your project didn't install Prettier in the dependencies then what happens if the latest version of Prettier in 2021 breaks the 2020 version? It might not break but we don't know that Prettier will release any update in the later version that cause a conflict. So safe bet is to install it as your dep.